# Unexpected '@' in program Xcode 7 and Receigen

Tags: xcode, xcode7, receigen

I just updated to Xcode 7.0 last night and it seems to have broken [Receigen](http://receigen.etiemble.com)'s generated code.

```
CFStringRef ReceiptValidation_str1 = @obfuscateCF@("");
```

Unexpected '@' in program

Receigen hasn't been updated since 2014, so this is almost certainly an Xcode 7 issue.

I reached out to the developer of Receigen and haven't heard back yet (it has only been a few hours).  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See "Get Bundle ID from build settings instead of info.plist".  I think it's the same issue, and I posted a work-around.

[Xcode Script - Get Bundle ID from build settings instead of info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446065)

Comment: I fixed it by hardcoding the Bundle ID into the info.plist file.  After updating to Xcode 7 it replaced the info.plist value with a dynamic placeholder.

Comment: I am having the exact problem.  My build is failing with on the line:

CFStringRef InAppValidation_str1 = @obfuscateCF@("");

But the fix here is not working for me.  Anyone have any more tips?

Answer (score 5):

In your Xcode Target, tab "Build Phases", edit your Receigen shell script. Replace the declaration `EXPANDED_BUNDLE_ID` that looked like:

```
EXPANDED_BUNDLE_ID=`eval \"echo $BUNDLE_ID\"
```

simply by the variable `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` (introduced in Xcode 7)

```
EXPANDED_BUNDLE_ID=$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
```

(you can also delete the old, now needless, declaration of `BUNDLE_ID`)

Your script should look like this:

```
# Receigen binary
RECEIGEN="/Applications/Receigen.app/Contents/MacOS/Receigen"

# Extract Info.plist information
INPUT="$INFOPLIST_FILE"
BUNDLE_VERSION=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INPUT"`

# Expand information if needed
EXPANDED_BUNDLE_ID=$PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER
EXPANDED_BUNDLE_VERSION=`eval "echo $BUNDLE_VERSION"`

# ...etc...
```

*Note: found this thanks to @mcgyver42's answer and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446065/xcode-script-get-bundle-id-from-build-settings-instead-of-info-plist)*